# Oracle localized sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

Can I have a sequence on a column which restarts itself depending on the value of another columnn i.e if column2 has a sequence, then for same values of column1, the sequence is maintained, for different value of column1 the sequence again starts from 0 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't because a sequence allows many users to create unique integers, so it cannot have dependencies.

If, for example, user A restarts the sequence (for a different value in col1) and then user B wants to add another row for prev value of col1 then col2 will not be unique...

You can do something like that programmatically and use `MAX(col2)+1`, but then you must maintain locks.

If all the values on col1 are known, maybe you can use different sequences for each value (but IMHO this is really ugly)